# Using DMA with two UART peripherals - is it possible?

Tags: stm32, uart, dma

I want to connect two UART peripherals using STM32G0 microcontroller via **DMA**. Not knowing the length of the messages in forward, I'm using function `HAL_UARTEx_ReceiveToIdle_DMA()` in order to receive them. Here is the part of my code:

**main.h**

```
.
.
.
    StartDMAReceptionOverUART1();
    StartDMAReceptionOverUART4();
  /* USER CODE END 2 */

  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  while (1)
  {
    /* USER CODE END WHILE */
        
    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
        HAL_Delay(10);  
    }
.
.
.
void StartDMAReceptionOverUART1(void)
{
    if (HAL_UARTEx_ReceiveToIdle_DMA(m_modulePort.huart, m_modulePort.rxBuffer, m_modulePort.rxBufferSize) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
    __HAL_DMA_DISABLE_IT(&hdma_usart1_rx, DMA_IT_HT);
    __HAL_DMA_DISABLE_IT(&hdma_usart1_rx, DMA_IT_TC);
}
void StartDMAReceptionOverUART4(void)
{
    if (HAL_UARTEx_ReceiveToIdle_DMA(m_meterPort.huart, m_meterPort.rxBuffer, m_meterPort.rxBufferSize) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
    __HAL_DMA_DISABLE_IT(&hdma_usart4_rx, DMA_IT_HT);
    __HAL_DMA_DISABLE_IT(&hdma_usart4_rx, DMA_IT_TC);
}
.
.
.
```

These functions are similar: first `HAL_UARTEx_ReceiveToIdle_DMA()` is checked, then *Half Transfer* and *Transfer Complete* interrupts are disabled in order to relieve processor (I need only IDLE interrupt). The **problem** is inside `StartDMAReceptionOverUART1()` function, `HAL_UARTEx_ReceiveToIdle_DMA()` never returns `HAL_OK` and program jumps on `Error_Handler()`. On the other hand, `StartDMAReceptionOverUART4()` works perfectly fine. What could be the problem?
Also, here is the receive callback function, also written inside **main.h**:

```
void HAL_UARTEx_RxEventCallback(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart, uint16_t Size)
{
    if(huart->Instance == m_meterPort.huart->Instance)                                // huart == UART4
    {
        memcpy(m_modulePort.txBuffer, m_meterPort.rxBuffer, Size);
        HAL_UART_Transmit_DMA(m_modulePort.huart, m_modulePort.txBuffer, Size);
        StartDMAReceptionOverUART4();
    }
    else if (huart->Instance == m_modulePort.huart->Instance)                        // huart == UART1                      
    {
        memcpy(m_meterPort.txBuffer, m_modulePort.rxBuffer, Size);
        HAL_UART_Transmit_DMA(m_meterPort.huart, m_meterPort.txBuffer, Size);                                                                       
    }
    else
    {
        return;
    }
}
```

Callback function, in dependence of the periphery, will copy received data to a buffer and send it to the other periphery (functions `memcpy()` and `HAL_UART_Transmit_DMA()`). DMA over UART4 is in **Normal** mode, therefore `StartDMAReceptionOverUART4()` is called, inside which is `HAL_UARTEx_ReceiveToIdle_DMA()`. On the other hand, DMA over UART1 is in **Circular** mode, so there is no need for calling `StartDMAReceptionOverUART4()`.

Comment: Are you using the same DMA for both receptions at the same time? If it were DMA1 on one thing and DMA2 on another, it must have worked. If it's the same DMA, you almost certainly have a conflict of configurations. It's likely you need to setup interrupt-based reception for both UART1 and UART4, and only after the first byte received, when you already know where you're receving data from, you can configure DMA accordingly (for UART1 or UART4, whichever communication is in progress) and receive the rest with DMA. If you have 1 DMA, you must also ensure there is only 1 communication at a time.

Comment: Mr. @Ilya, I am sorry for not answering at the proper period of time and would like to thank you on your answer. STM32G070 has only one DMA and conflict was inevitable due to the built-in priority of the DMA channels (communication can occur on both UART ports at the same time). Hence, I'll use DMA control on one port and interrupt service routine on another.